# Counting the number of committees

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose a leader wants to choose committees from a group of $n$ people, and that a committee can consist of at least 1 person. How many possible committees can the leader choose?

Comment: You just want the number of non-empty subsets of {$1,...,n$}, no?  So $2^n-1$.

Comment: Would you please give a formal answer @lulu, I mean write down a detailed  answer in the answer box, and not just a comment

Comment: Done.  Let me know if there is anything unclear in the answer.

Comment: Its okay @lulu, the answer is satisfactory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of this question, a committee is just a subset of $\{1,2,...,n\}$.  The (sensible) condition that it contain at least one person, just means that we want a non-empty subset.  There are $2^n$ subsets of a set of $n$ elements, so the answer is $$2^n-1$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the set of $n$ people as $\{p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n\}$. Now, consider a subset of these people. In the subset, we can either include person $p_1$ or not. Same for person $p_2$, and so on. So we can represent a subset of people by marking who is IN and who is OUT. E.g. $p_1$ is IN, $p_2$ is OUT, $p_3$ is OUT etc. Now, there are $n$ people. So we have a list of $n$ values, either IN or OUT. Since each value can be either IN or OUT, and there are two of these, we get $2 \times 2 \times 2 \times \dots \times 2 = 2^n$. Now, we must exclude the case where *everyone* is OUT, because that's an empty committee which is not allowed, so the final answer is $2^n - 1$.

Comment: So this must be another method, very ineresting

Comment: Actually this is just an elaboration of lulu's answer. The line in lulu's answer that says "There are $2^n$ subsets of a set of $n$ elements" is taken as given there, but in my answer I just spell out exactly why this is. You could also prove it inductively. Clearly there is $1$ subset of the empty set: itself. Then imagine adding an element, it's either IN or OUT. So we double what we had before, $2^n$ and get $2^{n + 1}$.

Comment: I concur entirely with what @Colm Bhandal says.  I trusted that the $2^n$ was known, but in case it is not, this solution gives a clear proof of it.